# Splash screen with more than one image on android

Tags: android, splash-screen, layer-list

Currently using the layer-list to achieve a splash screen with a drawable at the center. The app is targetting API 23+ so using bitmap is not mandatory unless it's necessary for what am trying to do. Basically I'm trying to pull off something similar to WhatsApp's new splash screen where the company reference is placed at the bottom of the screen.

[image: SplashScreen]

But for some reason, the second image is not being shown at all even though it's visible in the Android Studio preview distorted. What I have currently is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/black700" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_app_icon"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_company_mark"
        android:gravity="bottom|center" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I've noticed that the bottom item depends on the phone resolution on some phones. Maybe you need to add something like `<item android:bottom="50dp">` for your bottom item.

Comment: You are correct. Do you know any way to specify the bottom margin dynamically depending on the bottom bar height?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We ended up using a value which "looks good" on most phone resolutions. In case you figure out something else let me know ;)

Comment: Definitely will do. Gonna use this for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments I've noticed that the bottom item depends on the phone resolution on some phones. Why it depends on the resolution, I don't know.

To work around you can add padding at the bottom

```
<item android:bottom="50dp">
```

for your bottom item in your `layer-list` and it will show up.

I haven't found a way to dynamically set the value depending on something and therefore used a value which "looks good" for most display resolutions.